# How to resolve "module 'progressbar' has no attribute 'streams'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, progress-bar

Im trying to use [Mordor-Elastic.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OTRF/Security-Datasets/master/scripts/data-shippers/Mordor-Elastic.py) an script to ship security dataset (logs) to an elasticsearch distribution. The thing is, that the script has multiple progressbar functionality that doesnt work at my environment.

Example:

```
python Mordor-Elastic.py --url http://10.0.0.103:9200 inputs dataset.json
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'progressbar' has no attribute 'streams'
```

I've been investigating what to do, and the only thing that i found was to downgrade the progressbar module to version 2.5 which had the "stream" atribute. I did it with pip, but it stills not working.

```
pip show progressbar
Name: progressbar
Version: 2.5
Summary: Text progress bar library for Python.
Home-page: http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar
Author: Nilton Volpato
Author-email: nilton.volpato@gmail.com
License: LICENSE.txt
Location: c:\users\user1\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Any ideas about hoy to troubleshoot this?

Comment: `pip install progressbar2` I think you installed the wrong progressbar. Remove the old one and install progressbar2 or create a new virtual environment and install progressbar2. The author of `Security-Datasets` really should have included a `requirements.txt` file

Comment: It works! Completely agree with you about the requirementes.txt file xDD
Thank you!!!